# Default photo filters (Chrome) for Videos in camera app

Tags: ios, photos

Is there a way I can use the default filters (mainly Chrome) provided in Camera app for Video recording?

If somebody can point me to any 3rd party app that mimics chrome filter for video, it would be real great.

EDIT: I should be more clearer, I want filters while recording the videos, not for post processing.

Answer (score 1):

### [**Video Filters**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-filters-awesome-video/id793539948?mt=8)

This app is available to any iPhone or iPad running iOS 7 or higher.  It's a free app (as of the time of writing), and it comes with 8 filters, with another 7 available for purchase.  It is a standalone video-editing app.

Free filters:

> - Mono
> - Tonal
> - Noir
> - Fade
> - **Chrome**
> - Process
> - Transfer
> - Instant

Export format:

> - File Type : MPEG-4(Default), QuickTime
> - Retain Metadata
> - Optimize For Network Use

Comment: Sorry but it just add filters at the end. I want the filters to be applied while taking videos, just like it does with photos.

Comment: Have you tried [Chromic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chromic-video-filters-vintage/id724295125?mt=8)?  I haven't tried it myself, and their documentation seems to be scarce (or non-existent), but it seems to be an extension to the Photos app, so it might do what you're wanting... :)  Hope it helps!

Comment: it's too is for post processing

Comment: Oh, OK.  There's an app for about $3 that looks like it can filter videos live - it's called [VideoFilters](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-filters/id646865161?mt=8).  Have you tried that?  Sorry nothing else has been working!

Answer (score 0):

### iMovie *by Apple* -- Free on most newer devices.

To use iMovie, simply download the app (over 100MB), open Photos, find the video, click more options  [image], choose iMovie, then do whatever you want with your videos.

Official Guide: http://j.mp/imv_ios (Redirects to Apple's Knowledge Base)

iMovie can be used for editing videos, making slideshows, and more.